# How to compare *(void*) in С?

Tags: c

I have two variables of the type `void*` and size of type which is in `void*`.

```
int function(void* p1, void* p2, int size) {
  if (*p1 > *p2) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

How I can compare this the memory of which indicates pointers, or it's imposible, when I don't know types (double/int)?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare?"

Comment: A void pointer is just a memory address.  What do you propose to do with two memory addresses?

Comment: if you don't know what you're pointing to then how can you compare? If one points to a char and the other to a long how will you read the values to compare?

Comment: @RobertHarvey , In question there is *(void *), I know what I can't compare pointers

Comment: @phuclv , I know sizes, I write this in question

Comment: The question does not make sense. A `void *` does not have any other type besides `void *`. Do you mean the size of the type *pointed to by* that `void *`? What do you mean by comparing?!  What it is that you're trying to solve? Please write *more* than 3 sentences on the problem that you're trying to solve and preferably add some code too!

Comment: You can't dereference a `void *`.  Your compiler should be giving you at least a warning on that.

Comment: The only meaningful comparison you can make between two void pointer variables is to see if they're equal, which means they're pointing at the same memory address.

Comment: The only meaningful comparison you can make between two memory locations (if you don't know the data type), is to see if the bytes are the same using `memcmp()`.  A greater than/ less than comparison is not possible if you don't know the data type.

Comment: even after you edited and add the code it still doesn't make sense. A bit pattern has different values depending on the type it represents so without specifying type it's not possible to compare

Comment: The pattern of using a comparison function with 2 void* arguments is typical when using a pre-defined sort algorithm like qsort().  The sorting logic is already written, and you supply the function that knows how to compare two elements.  In this case, though, you the implementer know the data types stored in the list so you can cast them back to that type to do the comparison.  This is my guess as to where the problem came from.  It's not meaningful to have a comparison function where you literally don't have any way to know the original types of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression is invalid:

```
*p1 > *p2
```

Because you're attempting to dereference a `void *` which is not allowed.  You need to know what type these pointers point to in order to do a meaningful comparison.

However, the `size` argument to the function implies you know the size in bytes of the type the first two arguments points to and that both point to objects of the same type.  Given that, you can use `memcmp` to compare byte-by-byte what each of the two addresses point to.

```
int function(void* p1, void* p2, int size) {
  if (memcmp(p1, p2, size) > 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Note however that the result of the comparison depends very much on the type of the pointed-to object and the endianness of your system.

For example given `int` objects with the values 1 and 256, this function will return 0 on a little-endian and 1 on a big-endian system.

Comment: How I can compare one of this numbers with 0 or 0.0?

Comment: @THND One of *which* numbers?  It might help if you described how your function will get called.

Comment: I mean memcmp(p1, 0, size)

Comment: @THND 0 is a null pointer constant, so you can't dereference it.  Again, how is this function being used?

Comment: "I mean memcmp(p1, 0, size)". Do you want to know if `p1` points to a memory region filled with zeros?

Comment: Oh, I understood, sorry

Answer (score 3):

If you have two pointers and you know the size of the memory region they point to you can use `memcmp` to compare the contents of memory they point to:

```c
// Returns true if the contents of a and b are the same
bool compare(const void *a, size_t a_size, const void *b, size_t b_size)
{
    if (a_size != b_size)
    {
        // Different sizes, nothing to compare
        return false;
    }

    return memcmp(a, b, a_size) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With two `void*p1` and `void*p2` generic pointers, you syntactically could compare them using

```
if (p1 == p2) {
  // here p1 and p2 are pointer aliases, pointing to the same location
  // and we suppose that location is a string
  char*s = p;
  printf("string %s\n", s);
}
```

But you should know something *more* about these pointers. In particular the *actual* type of the data they are pointing to, and you should care about [data structure alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

Knowing the size of the pointed location is different. Your software should document *conventions* about that (since a `void*` generic pointer don't know the size or the type of pointed data).

To compare memory area by content, use [memcmp(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcmp.3.html). You need to be sure that the two pointers are valid (practically, in the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)), on Linux see [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and `/proc/self/maps`...)

On *some* systems (typical example: Linux/x86-64) you can compare generic pointers by converting them to `char*`.